# Como obter twitters usando a biblioteca tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter-api

Estou tentando obter twitters usando a biblioteca tweepy, a autenticação já consegui fazer, mas na hora de obter os twitters aparece uma mensagem de erro que pesquisei e não consigo resolver já que estou seguindo a documentação. Minha conta de desenvolvedor é ESSENTIAL.

```
import pandas as pd
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

api_key = '*****'
api_key_secret = '*****'
bearer_token = '*****'
access_token = '*****
access_token_secret = '*****

from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

resultados = api.search_recent_tweets()
```

O problema se encontra quando eu executo a ultima linha de código **resultados = api.search_recent_tweets()** aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro: **'API' object has no attribute 'search_recent_tweets'**, mas segundo a documentação: **https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets** a forma é essa.

Answer (score -2):

Se você esta chamando um "search" você tem que passar o que vc esta procurando, é exatamente isto que esta faltando, passar para dentro do "search_recent_tweets" o que vc quer

```
resultados = api.search_recent_tweets("iphone")
```

verifique na documentação e é o que informa, conforme link:
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html > API v2 > Search Recent Tweets